# Trouble chaining CSS animations

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I want to chain multiple animations together and I can't see what's wrong with my code (it only plays the second animation).

I know I could have made the goingup and goingdown animations just one animation (without chaining), but I want to insert a third animation in between these two animations and having three distinct animations seemed like the best approach.

```css
.customer-1 {
 -webkit-animation: goingup 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) .5s both;
         animation: goingup 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) .5s both;

 -webkit-animation: goingdown 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 1.2s both;
         animation: goingdown 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 1.2s both;
}


@keyframes goingup {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(1000px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes goingup {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(1000px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}


@keyframes goingdown {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(1000px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes goingdown {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(1000px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="customer-1">

 div content

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In CSS if you have:

```
.myElement {
  background-color: red;
  background-color: black; 
}
```

then only `background-color: black;` will be applied because it overwrites `background-color: red;`.

**SOLUTION**:

```css
.customer-1 {
  animation: goingdown 1s cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 1s forwards,
             goingup 1s cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 2s forwards;  
}


@keyframes goingup {
  from {
    transform: translateY(200px);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
}

@keyframes goingdown {
  from {
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateY(200px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="customer-1">
   div content
</div>
```

**Explanation:** 
The key here is to declare `animation` property only once and put all your `keyframe`s inside it:

```
animation: goingdown 1s cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 1s forwards,
             goingup 1s cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 2s forwards;
```

`goingdown` keyframe will start at `1s` and last for `1s`, then `goingup` starts at `2s` and it will last `1s`.